# Pass array of arguments without altering this

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the best way to pass an array of arguments to a function, but without altering (or addressing) the execution context.

I have this:

```
some_args = ["world"];
in.some.namespace.hello.apply(this, some_args);
```

Unfortunately this changes `hello`s execution context to the global object.

What's the slickest way of calling `hello` with `in.some.namespace` being the execution context?

Writing

```
in.some.namespace.hello.apply(in.some.namespace, some_args]
```

looks verbose and errorprone.

Answer (score 3):

> Writing
>
> ```
>  in.some.namespace.hello.apply(in.some.namespace.hello, some_args]
> ```
>
> looks verbose and errorprone.

*(In the below I've changed `in.` to `n.` because you can't declare a variable called `in` and I wanted to provide some live examples.)*

Three options, none of them really exciting: ;-)

1. Use `with`, despite its bad rep and incompatibility with strict mode
2. Write yourself a utility function
3. Use a disposable variable and don't mind some really funky-looking syntax

#### Use `with`:

```
with (n.some) {
    namespace.hello.apply(namespace, some_args);
}
```

*Slightly* less repetition, though there's still some, and you have to use `with`, which is disallowed in strict mode.

#### Utility function

Example utility function:

```js
function callWith(obj, name, args) {
  return obj[name].apply(obj, args);
}
var n = {
  some: {
    namespace: {
      hello: function(a, b, c) {
        alert(this.name + " says " + [a, b, c].join(", "));
      },
      name: "namespace"
    }
  }
};

callWith(n.some.namespace, "hello", [1, 2, 3]);
```

(Be careful doing that if you use a minifier that renames methods, as it probably won't update the string.)

#### Disposable variable and really funky syntax

I want to be clear that I'm *not recommending* this, just flagging it up as an option: If you have a variable you keep lying around for this purpose, you can do this:

```
(o = n.some.namespace, o.hello.apply(o, [1, 2, 3]));
```

E.g.:

```js
var o;
var n = {
  some: {
    namespace: {
      hello: function(a, b, c) {
        alert(this.name + " says " + [a, b, c].join(", "));
      },
      name: "namespace"
    }
  }
};

(o = n.some.namespace, o.hello.apply(o, [1, 2, 3]));
```

Arguably that's an *abusage* of the comma operator. At the very least. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to create a function delegate:

```
function $createDelegate(instance, method)
{
    return function (someArgs) { return method.apply(instance, someArgs); } 
}
```

Usage:

```
var delegate = $createDelegate(in.some.namespace, in.some.namespace.hello);
...
delegate(someArgs);
```

Which, for instance, is a very useful way to pass callbacks to an event Handler without loosing your context.

Comment: arguments contains the arguments used to call the callback. so it's a simple forward

Comment: Crowder is correct. I'm trying to find a terse way to invoke a function with an array of values as discrete arguments.

Comment: I've edited the response, please review the downvote ;)

Comment: I have removed the downvote, but I think you should remove the answer. I am not looking to create a function delegate. I am looking for a short syntax. Your suggestion is longer, not shorter, than doing function.apply(context, args)

Answer (score 0):

If the question is simply to write the line of code as short as possible, consider caching in a variable what's redundant (it's also better for perfs as it reduces the number of lookups):

```
var n = in.some.namespace;
n.hello.apply(n, some_args);
```